# How to access the first item in an object within an object on Open Library API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using the [Open Library API](https://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien) I am trying to get the first `lccn` from the array which is `2002044748` which looks something like this.

```
"first_publish_year": 1937,
"lccn": [
"2002044748",
"67029221",
"2013497341",
"38005859",
"2012545250",
"73008769",
"88156046",
"67000312",
"37038859",
"2007028554",
"84009023",
"2012278060",
"77078707",
"2002075940",
"88009061",
"98102207",
"90156122",
"2001276594",
"2012039220"
],
```

The `lccn - 2002044748` is equal to the book title `The Hobbit`.

If you will take a closer look on it, you'll be convince that it's an array but when I tried to get the type of it by using `typeof lccn` it returns an `object`. Even trying to get the first value like `lccn[0]` did not work since it's saying it's an object.

What I did is I tried to iterate on the object and see if value will be string since it looks like a string.

```
Object.entries(lccn).map(item => {
  console.log(typeof item);
});
```

But this returned an object again. I am really confuse on this. How do i get the first item from the `lccn` array that's actually equates to the `title`.

Any idea how? I am a newbie when it comes to array.

UPDATE:

I have the following codes on my component:

```
class BookListingScreen extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      books: [],
      errorMessage: '',
      isFetching: true,
    };
  }

  async fetchRandomBooks() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        'https://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien',
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      this.setState({books: json.docs, isFetching: false});
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({errorMessage: error});
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.fetchRandomBooks();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    let content = <BookList books={this.state.books} />;
    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      content = <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
    }
    return <View style={styles.container}>{content}</View>;
  }
}
```

Here's the booklist component:

```
export default class BookList extends Component {
  _keyExtractor = item => item.title;
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={{flex: 1}}
        data={this.props.books}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={({item} = this.props.books) => {
          return <BookItem item={item} />;
        }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

On my item list props:

```
export default class BookItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const {title, lccn} = this.props.item;

    console.log(lccn);

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
          <View style={{paddingRight: 5}}>
            {lccn.map(firstLccn => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri: `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/lccn/${firstLccn[0]}-M.jpg`,
                  }}
                  style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                />
              );
            })}
            <Text style={styles.cardTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to get the equivalent lccn for each title so I can get the first book cover image as stated on this [doc](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers).

Comment: Is `BookList` component passing individual array elements on to `BookItem`? Can you also include `BookList`? If `BookList` is basically doing something like `props.books.map(book => <BookItem item={book} />})` then `lccn` array would be accessed `props.item.lccn[0]`.

Comment: Thanks again drew. I added the BookList component.

Comment: Check my updated answer to see if the fix to the issue I found addresses the issue you see.

Comment: Thanks Drew so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `data.docs[0].lccn[0]`. The JSON you linked to has a `docs` array where the `lccn` is in the first element object.

```js
const data = {
  numFound: 296,
  start: 0,
  numFoundExact: true,
  docs: [
    {
      lccn: [
        "2002044748",
        "67029221",
        "2013497341",
        "38005859",
        "2012545250",
        "73008769",
        "88156046",
        "67000312",
        "37038859",
        "2007028554",
        "84009023",
        "2012278060",
        "77078707",
        "2002075940",
        "88009061",
        "98102207",
        "90156122",
        "2001276594",
        "2012039220"
      ]
    }
  ],
  num_found: 296,
  q: "",
  offset: null
};

console.log(data.docs[0].lccn[0]);
```

### Update

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
>     at BookItem.render (App.js.js:23:19
> ```

The issue in your code is that there are *some* `docs` (`books`) elements that don't have a `lccn` property. This isn't a problem until in `BookItem` you attempt to map the `lccn` array, but you can't since it's undefined.

```
class BookItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, lccn } = this.props.item;

    console.log(lccn); // <-- some undefined values logged

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
          <View style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>
            {lccn.map((firstLccn) => { // <-- blows up here
              return (
                ...
              );
            })}
            ...
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

See this running [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/how-to-access-the-first-item-in-an-object-within-an-object-on-open-library-api) for your code and check the console log.

[image]

To resolve you can either provide a valid, mappable fallback value when destructuring:

```
const { title, lccn = [] } = this.props.item;
```

Or you can use the Optional Chaining operator to guard against the potentially null/undefined value.

```
{lccn?.map((firstLccn) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
})}
```

Code

```
class BookItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, lccn } = this.props.item;

    console.log(lccn);

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.cardContainerStyle}>
          <View style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>
            {lccn?.map((firstLccn) => (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: `https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/lccn/${firstLccn[0]}-M.jpg`,
                }}
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
              />
            ))}
            <Text style={styles.cardTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I already called this out inside my api call `let response = await fetch(
        'https://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=tolkien',
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      this.setState({books: json.docs, isFetching: false});`

Comment: I destructure the elements via `const {title, lccn} = this.props.item;` on my other component. Title works but lccn returns a long array. I just need the equivalent lccn to the title.

Comment: @ChristianMargaritaGaza Ok, so `json.docs` will be the array, and you save it into `this.state.books`, so to access now it would be `this.state.books[0].lccn[0]`. What is `this.props.item`? Can you update your question to include all your relevant code trying to access into this object? It would be easier than you providing it a snippet at-a-time in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the first element of an array, you do this:

`lccn[0]`

The number in the braces is the index of the item. In arrays the first index is 0.

If you want to console.log all elements in an array after eachother, you can do this with the map function.

```
lccn.map((item)=>{
  console.log(item)
})
```

Comment: taskqueue Cannot read properties of undefined reading map

Answer (score 0):

I saw the `lccn` you show is an object with key `lccn`.

SO you can get value by: `lccn.lccn[0]`

Comment: cannot read property of undefined reading 0 it says

Comment: console.log(lccn) before use it

Comment: It returned lots of arrays on the console https://prnt.sc/1roxejz

Comment: I need to pull out the equivalent lccn for each title. https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers

Answer (score -1):

**If you want the first element then simply use arr_name[0]. [0] is the index of the very first item**.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.